# How to get bounding box that contains all items in Paper.js?

Tags: paperjs

How can we get the bounding `Rectangle` that contains all items in the project?

Currently I'm calculating them one by one:

```
calc-bounds = (scope) ->
    fit = {}
    for layer in scope.project.layers
        for item in layer.children
            for <[ top left ]>
                if item.bounds[..] < fit[..] or not fit[..]?
                    fit[..] = item.bounds[..]
            for <[ bottom right ]>
                if item.bounds[..] > fit[..] or not fit[..]?
                    fit[..] = item.bounds[..]
    #console.log "fit bounds: ", fit
    top-left = new scope.Point fit.left, fit.top
    bottom-right = new scope.Point fit.right, fit.bottom
    new scope.Rectangle top-left, bottom-right
```

## Rationale

A "Fit all" function that sets `project.center` and `project.zoom` will need this calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just [unite](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#unite-path) (merge) all the [bounds](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#bounds) from all elements.

This will return a [Rectangle](http://paperjs.org/reference/rectangle/) that tightly fits all the elements, a.k.a a Bounding Box.

Here's a [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/pZJBasMwEEWvMvUmDhjHCS0Fg1toeoDS0lWchWxPYmF5ZGSpKQTfvZKsNtmGaqf5o3lfXzpHxHqM8uijQ123URLVsnH7L6aAa+xHKGBXEthFeII3ptt0y1UtMD7PZbcGOXLNJeVzk+Sk43WWJbDJsmVy6VOs4WbM4SG7Kh64EFsppMphUQmDi1mafg/eyN047uNt2MGoQfwXfO/A6xsv3LMjkmZ/6JL2JZW0WsEn2fyBCQGVNNSMcFCy93v/LmlJ7o2M62pe5o4iSAobU2McV5X8TnxtCcUTBP8KtVEEd06FZy+nAZGDK6Z+aHwlWFtTAmSEWAZ3r4qdQLcYDASPwZSfXFzye8daMzraCK/t2lGeNmolO/SB2EP2C7C6WziM/Y2VQtYNLt4xynf76Qc=).

And here's the code:

```
var items = [
    new Path.Circle({
        position: new Point(100, 200),
        radius: 50,
        fillColor: 'blue'
    }),
    new Path.Circle({
        position: new Point(200, 70),
        radius: 50,
        fillColor: 'purple'
    }),
    new Path.Circle({
        position: new Point(400, 100),
        radius: 50,
        fillColor: 'magenta'
    })
]

// Unite all bounds from all items.
var unitedBounds = items.reduce((bbox, item) => {
    return !bbox ? item.bounds : bbox.unite(item.bounds)
}, null)

// Draw the united bounds.
var bbox = new Path.Rectangle(unitedBounds)
bbox.strokeColor = 'black'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the layer bounds or group the element you want to bound instead of doing the reduce trick from @nicholaswmin

Here is [a sketch with both solutions](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.7/S/pVM7T8MwEP4rVpYmUpWm4SVFYoAisTAgEGIgHS7x0Zi6dmQ7lKrqf8d2mpAglgpv+e57nO/ifSBgg0EWPK/RlFUwDUpJ3XcphTaEGdxock3eckHsEbglj2CqeMFUyTHct7A7tdTMMCmyliSZMOE8SaYkTZJo+sNTQFmjM3KRDMB3xvlCcqkyMil4g5O2dOiEJ+amLvfqtNi6UTX/b/C5C56feOENrFAY6KNzscxFLmYz8qKRmAoJhx0qUshGUJ2LdjMeu/WQ3U+t5AeWJobSsE98cLW443ureyWbmgDntlukSI+bBUFJc0wZ+6+coPcP3R29R+iFUTS2v1OwHZjEnUtRyC8r78f4ZJsEsbKTHPQfDdnp3/RBO5HLdNRYGyXX+MqoqazqbIT66Vq0+5/aYvpLczmGe5FCOulKFHR1oxTs3DuY+wX7Bdm3UiiEde1Wr4PsbXn4Bg==)

```js
const items = [
    new Path.Circle({
        position: new Point(100, 200),
        radius: 50,
        fillColor: 'blue'
    }),
    new Path.Circle({
        position: new Point(200, 70),
        radius: 50,
        fillColor: 'purple'
    }),
    new Path.Circle({
        position: new Point(400, 100),
        radius: 50,
        fillColor: 'magenta'
    })
]

// Use the layer bounds
const layerBounds = project.activeLayer.bounds

// Group all needed items and use the bounds
const groupBounds = (new Group(items)).bounds

// Draw the bounds.
const bbox = new Path.Rectangle(layerBounds)
const bbox2 = new Path.Rectangle(groupBounds)

bbox.strokeWidth = 3
bbox.strokeColor = 'blue'

bbox2.strokeWidth = 6
bbox2.strokeColor = 'red'
bbox2.dashArray = [10, 10]
```